# I want to send an auto-response emails from the lead owner's email when a new lead is created. How can I do this?

Tags: leads, web2lead, lead-auto-response

We are using Web2Lead forms to capture leads e-mails and info into SF.

Upon creating a new lead, the lead is assigned to one of our users using assignment rules. At this point we want to to be able to send an auto-responder from the lead owner's email to the lead (customer) but we do not understand what customisation is required to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Normally to send to the Customer contact (your lead) you would use Auto-Response Rules to achieve this as your first port of call.

There are some things to consider which help determine which path is best - this is useful

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=rules_differences_auto_workflow.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

I would use a workflow rule.  Setup->Build->Create->Workflow & Approvals -> Workflow rules->New rule-> choose Lead object.  Then, assuming you don't need to do anything else I would select "evalute the rule when the record is created".  This will only trigger the rule once for that record.  From there, you can go figure the selection criteria to trigger an email to the record owner that Web2Lead assigned to the lead.  The wizard will walk you through but come back with questions if any.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How many hours of work would this take, in your opinion, if we were to pay someone to do this?

Comment: would take me 15 mins max in my org if you have the email content already.  Maybe as much as 45-60 mins if someone's not familiar with your instance.